# Asymptotics of multinomial coefficients

Tags: st.statistics, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients, entropy, multinomial-coefficients

Binomial coefficients have a well known asymptotics (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas) given by $$\binom nk\sim\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}} e^{-d^2/(2n)} \sim \frac{2^n}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}n \pi }} e^{-d^2/(2n)}.$$

Is there corresponding asymptotics for multinomials (I am more interested in what happens analogously in the denominator)?

Comment: Use Stirling’s formula?

Comment: Well not clear to me how expression behaves under multiple parameters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose that $k$ is a fixed natural number, $n\to\infty$,  and
\begin{equation*}
    a_i=\frac nk+o(n^{2/3})
\end{equation*}
for each $i$; here in what follows, $i\in\{1,\dots,k\}$.
Let
\begin{equation*}
    h_i:=\frac kn\,a_i-1=o(n^{-1/3}), \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
so that $h_i\to0$ and
\begin{equation}
    a_i=\frac nk\,(1+h_i). \tag{2} 
\end{equation}
By Stirling's formula,
\begin{equation*}
    n!\sim(2\pi)^{1/2} n^{1/2}\Big(\frac ne\Big)^n
\end{equation*}
and, by (2),
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    a_i!&\sim(2\pi)^{1/2} \Big(\frac nk\Big)^{1/2}(1+h_i)^{1/2}\Big(\frac n{ke}(1+h_i)\Big)^{a_i} \\ 
    &\sim(2\pi)^{1/2} \Big(\frac nk\Big)^{1/2}\Big(\frac n{ke}(1+h_i)\Big)^{a_i}. 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Therefore and because $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i=n$,
\begin{equation*}
    \prod_{i=1}^k a_i!\sim(2\pi)^{k/2} \Big(\frac nk\Big)^{k/2}\Big(\frac n{ke}\Big)^n
    \prod_{i=1}^k(1+h_i)^{a_i}, 
\end{equation*}
which implies
\begin{equation*}
    \binom{n}{a_1,\ldots,a_k}=\frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^k a_i!}
    \sim(2\pi)^{1/2-k/2}\frac{n^{1/2}}{(n/k)^{k/2}}\frac{k^n}{e^u}, 
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    u:=\sum_{i=1}^k a_i\ln(1+h_i)=\frac nk\sum_{i=1}^k (1+h_i)\ln(1+h_i), 
\end{equation*}
by (2).
Note also that (i) $(1+h)\ln(1+h)=h+h^2/2+O(|h|^3)$ as $h\to0$, (ii) $\sum_{i=1}^k h_i=0$ (by the definition of $h_i$ in (1) and the condition $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i=n$), and (iii) $h_i=o(n^{-1/3})$. It follows that
\begin{equation*}
    u=\frac n{2k}\,\sum_{i=1}^k h_i^2+o(1)=\frac k{2n}\,\sum_{i=1}^k(a_i-n/k)^2+o(1). 
\end{equation*}
Thus,
\begin{equation*}
    \binom{n}{a_1,\ldots,a_k}
    \sim(2\pi n)^{1/2-k/2}k^{n+k/2}\exp\Big\{-\frac k{2n}\,\sum_{i=1}^k(a_i-n/k)^2\Big\}. 
\end{equation*}

In particular, when $k=2$, we get the Wikipedia result quoted in the OP:
\begin{equation*}
    \binom na\sim\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{\pi n/2 }} e^{-2(a-n/2)^2/n} 
\end{equation*}
if $n\to\infty$ and $a=\frac n2+o(n^{2/3})$.

Comment: Is it $(n) +k/2$ or $(n+k)/2$ in exponent?

Comment: @VS. : Everything seems correct as written. Why the doubt?

Comment: Pretty sure it was $(n)+k/2$ that you implied but nevertheless wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 5):

The analogous estimate in the range where your formula is valid (that is, $a_i=\frac nk+o(n^{1/2})$ - note Wikipedia claims the binomial case is valid for $a_i=\frac n2+o(n^{2/3})$, but I wasn't able to reproduce that estimate) is:
$$
\binom{n}{a_1\ a_2\ \ldots\ a_k}
\sim
\frac{k^n}{(2\pi n)^{(k-1)/2}}\exp\left(-\frac kn\sum_{i=1}^k b_i^2\right),
$$
where $b_i=a_i-\frac nk$, that is the difference of $a_i$ from its central value.

This can be obtained by using Stirling's formula, and estimates on quantities of the form $(1+\frac an)^n$.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis above has the correct version of what I was trying to say...

Comment: Doesn't $o(n^{2/3})$ seem wrong? For $n/2 - k = O(n^k)$ where $1/2 < k < 2/3$, the position of $k$ in the normal approximation would keep moving to the left, wouldn't it? (If you get my meaning.)

Answer (score 1):

Up to Theorem 5 in [this article by Raygorodskiy](https://lectoriy.mipt.ru/file/synopsis/pdf/Maths-DiscreteAnalysis-M01-Raygorodskiy-150522.01.pdf),
$${\lfloor na_1 \rfloor +\lfloor na_2 \rfloor\,+ \dots +\lfloor na_k \rfloor\ \choose \lfloor na_1 \rfloor ,\,\lfloor na_2 \rfloor , \, \dots , \lfloor na_k \rfloor\,} =\left(\frac 1 {a_1^{a_1}a_2^{a_2}\cdots a_k^{a_k}}+o(1)\right)^n$$ as $n\to \infty$, assuming $a_j>0,\ j=1\dots k,$ and $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_k=1.$

Comment: I believe the OP is asking for more precise asymptotics than this (this is describing the denominator but not the numerator).

Comment: @ Anthony Quas: Thank you for your personal opinion. Criticism should be constructive. Can you present another asymptotics? TIA.

Comment: I refer to the original question; not to my personal opinion. By the way: the original question does include more precise asymptotics in the binomial case, and the OP is fairly explicitly asking for similarly precise asymptotics in the multinomial case.in the central case the OP is asking about, your asymptotics are simply $(k+o(1))^n$, whereas I believe the OP is looking for something like $Ck^n/n^{(k-1)/2}$.

Comment: @ Anthony Quas: Sorry, but the asymptotics in theorem 5 is not $(k+o(1))^n $. Thank you for your personal opinion again.

Comment: This is my personal algebra. Take $a_1=\ldots=a_k=1/k$ and multiply.

Comment: @ Anthony Quas: Thank you for your explanation of your specification of theorem 5. As far as I understand you, your $Ck^n/n^{(k−1)/2}$ is related only to this very special case.

Comment: The estimate that the OP quoted is (per the Wikipedia page that he cites) valid for $k=n/2+o(n^{2/3})$. The estimate that I hinted at (once the Gaussian decay term is included) should hold in the corresponding range: $a_i=n/k+o(n^{2/3})$.